# How to call a method of another class in another package, which has its own parameters?

Tags: java, bluej

**Class1**

```
package package1;

public class Class1
{
    public double function1(double parameter1, double parameter2)
    {
        //my function here, which returns something, for e.g:
        return(parameter1 + parameter2)
    }
}
```

**Class2**

```
import package1.Class1;

public class Class2
{
    public double function2(double parameter3)
    {
        //I want to use the result of the "function1" (which uses parameters)
        //in this function here like this:
        double variable1;
        Class1 obj1 = new Class1()
        variable1 = obj1.function1(parameter1, parameter2)
    }
}
```

If I declare the variables "parameter1" and "parameter2" INSIDE the "function1" (and initialize them there-itself), it returns no error. But if I put "parameter1" and "parameter2" as PARAMETERS of "function1", then it returns an error: "cannot find variable parameter1". What should I do???

Comment: Read about variable scope. Local variables in one method have no relation to local variables in another.

Comment: where is variable a ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put *class* before Class1 and before Class2.
You forgot to put ; at end of your statements and declare the package of Class2.

We don't exactly see variable a, post more code.

Comment: We can reasonably assume that this is pseudo code. This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see a variable `a` in the snippet you've provided, but I think that you're misunderstanding the purpose of variables in methods.

Take, for example, this mathematical function:

[image]

We define a function parameterized with x to be equivalent to the quotient presented there.

When we use the method in math, we don't use x - we put in a number we want, such as f(2), or f(0), or f(4).

In your case, what you want to do is provide `function1` with the arguments it needs, similar to a mathematical function.

So...I'd think something like this:

```
variable3 = obj1.function1(1.0, 2.0);
```

There may be some extreme headaches with adding floating-point values, but that is left as an exercise for the reader (and Stack Overflow here has a ton of resources on the matter).